# Is there a Reflector add-in or other tool that will handle auto properties?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, reflector, automatic-properties

Reflector shows this for auto properties:

```
public string AddressLine1
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    get
    {
        return this.<AddressLine1>k__BackingField;
    }
    [CompilerGenerated]
    set
    {
        this.<AddressLine1>k__BackingField = value;
    }
}
```

Is there any add-in or other tool that will convert it to:

```
public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
```

I don't believe that any of these add-ins support the above: http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins

buy would be happy if you proved me wrong.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would be the benefit of such an add-on?

Comment: I'm struck by that curiosity bug too! ;-)

Comment: It's quicker to export code with FileDisassembler.
I have a 3rd party library which would be useful to debug into thus decompiling and exporting it is useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current version of Reflector shows auto properties properly in the disassembler if the language is set to C# and the optimization is set to .NET 3.5. It only shows auto properties in that manner if the optimization is set to .NET 2.0. Select View -> Options and set the Optimization setting on the Disassembler options page.

Comment: Cool. Do you know if this will affect the output of the FilDisassembler addin? I'll try it myself.